# yum install mysql & mysql-server transaction e

Tags: linux, centos

The question is, I have run yum remove, yum cleanup, yum-complete-transaction... there is no mysql installed currently, but I'm getting the following errors. I manually removed the files and did an updatedb, what do I do to get past this and get mysql and mysql-server installed (mysql-server has similar errors)?

Thanks!

```
 Package                                                     Arch                                                       Version                                                               Repository                                                            Size
=========================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql                                                       i386                                                       5.1.52-jason.1                                                        utterramblings                                                       3.5 M

Transaction Summary
=========================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)
Upgrade       0 Package(s)

Total size: 3.5 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/mysql from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/bin/mysql_waitpid from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/bin/mysqladmin from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/bin/mysqlbinlog from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/bin/mysqlcheck from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/bin/mysqldump from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/bin/mysqlimport from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/bin/mysqlshow from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/bin/mysqlslap from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_find_rows.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_waitpid.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlaccess.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqladmin.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlshow.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlslap.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-community-5.1.45-1.rhel5.i386
```

Comment: Did you try and remove "MySQL-client"?

Also, this is probably better suited for superuser.com